# DC circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

In the below circuit when I solved in methods A and B the current in the 2 ohms resistor is **3.4** A.

However, in method C the current in the 2 ohms resistor is **0.9** A.

### Where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: What is 2.5 A + 0.9 A? And do you see why I'm asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Where is my mistake?*

The mistake you have made is assuming the same current will flow through the 2 Ω resistor when you have converted the 5 volt source to a current source in parallel with it.

Consider a 5 volt source and 2 Ω resistor on their own with **nothing else connected**...

Does current flow through the 2 Ω series resistor when there is no load? If you then convert to a current source and parallel resistor then of course 2.5 amps will flow through the 2 Ω parallel resistor.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

V=1.8 is correct since Req=1.2 ohms but from (C)   I2+I3 = **4A-2.5A=1.5A**

1.5x1.2 = 1.8 V

Now it should be clear what I2 is and you found your mistake.